# Minimum element out of a list, with a specific function

Tags: c, function, arraylist, linked-list

I have to run a program using a function on a linked list with array and indices, that writes the minimum element of the list on a variable pointed by a pointer.
I also have to use this function as shown here:

```
        void minimum(struct list* ptr, unsigned int * varPtr){
        unsigned int min, position;

        for(position=ptr->buffer[ptr->first].next,
            min=ptr->buffer[ptr->first].value; 
            position != ptr->size;
            position=ptr->buffer[position].next) {
           if (min > ptr->buffer[position].value);
              min=ptr->buffer[position].value;
              printf("%d\n",min);
            }
        *varPtr = min;
    }
```

Unfortunately, every time I run the code, the last printf always returns not the minimum but the last element in the list, no matter if smaller or bigger than others.
I'm pretty sure that inizializing and inserting functions work properly, but can't find the error.
Thank you for the help.

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



/*
     * defining my list
     */

struct record {
    int value;
    int next;
};

struct list {
    int first;
    int free;
    int size;
    struct record* buffer;
};


void init(struct list* ptr, int dimensione){
    ptr->buffer = (struct record *) malloc(dimensione*sizeof(struct record));
    ptr->size = dimensione;
    ptr->first = ptr -> size; //valore illegale

    /*
     * order I want
     * 1 -> 3 -> 0 -> 4 -> 2
     */

    ptr->free = 1;
    ptr->buffer[0].next = 3;
    ptr->buffer[1].next = 0;
    ptr->buffer[2].next = 4;
    ptr->buffer[3].next = 2;
    ptr->buffer[4].next = ptr->size; 

}

/*
 * bottom inserting
 */
bool insert( struct list* ptr, int value ){
    int moved;
    int * position_ptr;

    if(ptr->free != ptr->size){
        moved = ptr -> free;
        ptr->free = ((ptr->buffer)[ptr->free]).next;
        position_ptr = &ptr->first;
        while(*position_ptr != ptr->size){
            position_ptr = &(((ptr->buffer)[*position_ptr]).next);
        }
        *position_ptr = moved;
        ptr->buffer[moved].value = value;
        ptr->buffer[moved].next = ptr -> size;

        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
/*
 * I MUST use EXACTLY this function 
 */
void minimum(struct list* ptr, unsigned int * varPtr){
        unsigned int min, position;

        for(position=ptr->buffer[ptr->first].next,
            min=ptr->buffer[ptr->first].value; 
            position != ptr->size;
            position=ptr->buffer[position].next) {
           if (min > ptr->buffer[position].value);
              min=ptr->buffer[position].value;
              printf("%d\n",min);
            }
        *varPtr = min;
    }

void visit (struct list * ptr){
    int position;
    position = ptr->first;
    while(position!=ptr->size){
        printf("%d\n", ptr->buffer[position].value);
        position=ptr->buffer[position].next;
    }
}
int main(void){
    struct list mylist;
    init(&mylist, 5);

    insert(&mylist, 10);
    insert(&mylist, 20);
    insert(&mylist, 50);
    insert(&mylist, 35);

    int min_element;
     minimum(&mylist,&min_element);
     visit(&mylist);

    printf("min value: %d\n", min_element);
    fflush(stdout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply a code formatter to the 'unchangeable' function `minimum()`, you find that there is a (big) bug in it:

```
static void minimum(struct list *ptr, unsigned int *varPtr)
{
    unsigned int min, position;

    for (position = ptr->buffer[ptr->first].next,
         min = ptr->buffer[ptr->first].value;
         position != ptr->size;
         position = ptr->buffer[position].next)
    {
        if (min > ptr->buffer[position].value)
            ;
        min = ptr->buffer[position].value;
        printf("%d\n", min);
    }
    *varPtr = min;
}
```

The semicolon at the end of the `if` is a null statement, and it renders the `if` condition pointless.

So, you need to look very carefully at where you got the 'unchangeable' code from.  If the code is correctly transcribed, then there's an unfixable bug because the code is unchangeable.  More likely, you've got a transcription error and removing that stray semicolon will fix your problem.  Well, the `printf()` inside the loop is also problematic.  It should probably be at the end of the function, outside the loop.

The function is also poorly designed; it should return the minimum value, not print it.  The calling code could do that.  The printing makes the function very specialized.  (OK: it returns the minimum value via the pointer argument.  It would be better to return it as a value.)

There's a discrepancy between the types used in the function (`unsigned int`) and the types used in the structure (`int`).  When I compile, I get shouted at for mixing signed and unsigned integers in comparisons.  Fix up enough `int` to `unsigned int`, and you can end up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct record
{
    unsigned value;
    unsigned next;
};

struct list
{
    unsigned first;
    unsigned free;
    unsigned size;
    struct record *buffer;
};

static void init(struct list *ptr, int dimensione)
{
    ptr->buffer = (struct record *)malloc(dimensione * sizeof(struct record));
    ptr->size = dimensione;
    ptr->first = ptr->size;

    ptr->free = 1;
    ptr->buffer[0].next = 3;
    ptr->buffer[1].next = 0;
    ptr->buffer[2].next = 4;
    ptr->buffer[3].next = 2;
    ptr->buffer[4].next = ptr->size;
}

static bool insert(struct list *ptr, int value)
{
    unsigned moved;
    unsigned *position_ptr;

    if (ptr->free != ptr->size)
    {
        moved = ptr->free;
        ptr->free = ((ptr->buffer)[ptr->free]).next;
        position_ptr = &ptr->first;
        while (*position_ptr != ptr->size)
        {
            position_ptr = &(((ptr->buffer)[*position_ptr]).next);
        }
        *position_ptr = moved;
        ptr->buffer[moved].value = value;
        ptr->buffer[moved].next = ptr->size;

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

static void minimum(struct list *ptr, unsigned int *varPtr)
{
    unsigned int min, position;

    for (position = ptr->buffer[ptr->first].next,
         min = ptr->buffer[ptr->first].value;
         position != ptr->size;
         position = ptr->buffer[position].next)
    {
        if (min > ptr->buffer[position].value)
            min = ptr->buffer[position].value;
        printf("%d\n", min);
    }
    *varPtr = min;
}

static void visit(struct list *ptr)
{
    unsigned position;
    position = ptr->first;
    while (position != ptr->size)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ptr->buffer[position].value);
        position = ptr->buffer[position].next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct list mylist;
    init(&mylist, 5);

    insert(&mylist, 10);
    insert(&mylist, 20);
    insert(&mylist, 50);
    insert(&mylist, 35);

    unsigned min_element;
    minimum(&mylist, &min_element);
    printf("List:\n");
    visit(&mylist);

    printf("min value: %u\n", min_element);
    fflush(stdout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the output is then:

```
10
10
10
List:
10
20
50
35
min value: 10
```

Various alternative sets of values also show the correct minimum.

The tree structure is very peculiar — unusual to say the least.

Comment: yes the printf inside the loop was a control. Anyway thank you so much